# D3.js: alternative to selecting elements by data attributes?

Tags: d3.js

I'm using D3.js to build a circular heat chart, and I want to add events so that when I mouseover any section of the chart, all the elements at the same angle also highlight. (Like the mouseover events on [this Guardian visualisation](http://www.theguardian.com/world/interactive/2012/may/08/gay-rights-united-states).)

At the moment, I'm doing this by explicitly adding data attributes to the HTML for every `path` element:

```
 g.selectAll("path").data(data)
   .enter().append("path")
   .attr("d", d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(ir).outerRadius(or).startAngle(sa).endAngle(ea))
   .attr("data-pathnumber", function(d) { return d.pathNumber });
```

And then my mouseover event selects by data attribute:

```
d3.selectAll("#chart4 path").on('mouseover', function() {
  var d = d3.select(this).data()[0];
  d3.selectAll('path[data-pathnumber="' + d.pathNumber + '"]').attr('fill', 'black');
});
```

However, is this actually the correct way to do things in D3? It feels to me like there "ought" to be a way to select the path based only on the data stored in the DOM, not on explicit data attributes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you store the reference to your paths, you can use selection.filter here:

```
var paths = g.selectAll("path").data(data)
   .enter().append("path")
   .attr("d", d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(ir).outerRadius(or).startAngle(sa).endAngle(ea))
;
```

Mouseover:

```
d3.selectAll("#chart4 path").on('mouseover', function(thisData) {
    paths
        .filter(function (d) { return d.pathNumber === thisData.pathNumber; })
        .attr('fill', 'black');
});
```

Comment: d3.select(this).data()[0].pathNumber can be replaced by m.pathNumber if the mouseover function takes 'm' as a parameter.