# D3.js, circularHeatChart highlight ring on mouseover

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mouseover, highlight

I'm doing a school project on web-development and our teacher doesn't have a clue on the area that he should be teaching so I've been surfing trough the net in hopes of finding an answer.

My problem being, I'm supposed to edit a JavaScript code for a circular heat map so that the level of the circle would highlight on 'mouseover' also while showing the data of the segment that mouse hovers on, I found a answer close to what I'm doing:

[answer for Richard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18056716/d3-js-alternative-to-selecting-elements-by-data-attributes)

But sadly seem to be unable to put that information to good use, seeing as I have only little clue on what I'm doing...

The code that I'm testing this all:

```
d3.select('#chart4')
.selectAll('svg')
.data([data])
.enter()
.append('svg')
.call(chart)
.selectAll('path')
;

/*   //this should contain some of the information needed for the highlight...
var paths = g.selectAll("path")
.data(data) 
.enter()
.append("path") 
.attr("d",d3.svg.arc()
.innerRadius(ir)
.outerRadius(or)
.startAngle(sa)
.endAngle(ea));
*/

d3.selectAll("#chart4 path").on('mouseover', function() {
var d = d3.select(this).data()[0];
d3.select("#info").text(d.title + ' has value ' + d.value);
    //should find a way to connect this witht the highlight one

});

/*  //this function should make the highlight work, sadly I seem to be missing code
d3.selectAll("#chart4 path").on('mouseover', function() {
paths
.filter(function (d) { return d.pathNumber === thisData.pathNumber; })
.attr('fill', 'black'); });
*/

d3.selectAll("#chart4 svg").on('mouseout', function() {
d3.select("#info").text(''); });
```

Also shown here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yH75y/)

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805184/d3-show-data-on-mouseover-of-circle/10806220#10806220) should help. Works the same for `path` elements.

Comment: The question indicated would probably help me, if I could just understand how...

Comment: Could you provide a complete example please?

Comment: Updated the text, also attached JSFiddle link of it

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/yH75y/1/)?

Comment: Close but not quite, I'm trying to highlight the whole circle the segment is on.

Comment: Well this is a bit hacky, but it works: http://jsfiddle.net/yH75y/2/