# d3 selectAll Confusion

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I am confused about the selection methods in D3. according to the description on [Github](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections) using the D3.selectAll(selector) method selects all elements that match the specified selector. The elements will be selected in document traversal order (top-to-bottom). If no elements in the current document match the specified selector, returns the empty selection.

So then given the data:

```
XValue     Yvalue     type A     type B    X2Value    Y2Value
1          2          A          A1        1          1
1          2          A          A2        1          1
```

on a click event how would I reference all data points with type A =  "A" right now I use `d3.select(this) which will require in this instance 2 clicks on the same point in order to operate on the two data points. Instead I would like to be able to reference all with an type A = "A" attribute so that I can switch between X2 Y2 values and X1 Y1 values.

My confusion then is how to write in a `d3.selectAll(this)`

### EDIT

It would seem that the way to go about this would be to use the method `d3.nest()`
so that that data is properly linked. But then I still need to dynamically allocate `this` to the proper key

```
d3.csv('AcreageData.csv', function (data) {

var nestedCsv = d3.nest()
        .key(function (d) { return d.type A; })
        .entries(data);

 var circles = svg.selectAll('circle')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')

    .attr('cx',function (d,i) { 
        return xScale(nestedCsv[i].values.X2Value) })   
    .attr('cy',function (d,i) { 
        return yScale(nestedCsv[i].values.Y2Value) })   
    .attr('r',function (d,i) { 
        return Math.abs(rScale(nestedCsv[i].values.Radii))})    
    .attr('fill',function (d,i) { 
        return cScale(nestedCsv[i].values.TypeA); })
    .attr("stroke",function (d,i) { 
        return cScale(nestedCsv[i].values.TypeA); })    
    .attr('stroke-width',4)

    .on('click', function (d) {
    d3.select(this)
    .transition()
    .attr('r', 50)
    .duration(500)
    .attr('cx',function (d,i) { 
            return xScale(nestedCsv[i].values.XValue) })
    .attr('cy',function (d,i) { 
            return yScale(nestedCsv[i].values.Yvalue) })
    .attr('r',function (d,i) { 
            return Math.abs(rScale(nestedCsv[i].radii))})
    .attr('fill', "none")
    .attr("stroke",function (d,i) { 
            return cScale(nestedCsv[i].TypeA); })
    .attr('stroke-width',4)
     })
```

This conclusion I came to reading http://www.jeromecukier.net/blog/2012/05/28/manipulating-data-like-a-boss-with-d3/ In his example he can directly select by name what he wishes to animate but because I wish to do mouseclicks I need this to reference the point selected and all of its related points. definitely this is the right approach but im stumbling on syntax

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18056716/d3-js-alternative-to-selecting-elements-by-data-attributes)?

Comment: Yes! I think this should get me going down the right path information wise,

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably need to provide a DOM example for us to fully understand what you are doing, but typically you'd be using `select` or `selectAll` on DOM elements.

So for example you'd use the following to select a whole load of circles and change the colour on all of them at once:

`d3.selectAll("circle").style("color", "red");`

A good article on the subject to fully explore is [Mike Bostock's 3 Little Circles](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/circles/).

For your particular question you simply want to start accessing your data (you wouldn't use `d3.select` for this). Pretend your data is an array and simply filter it:

```
var typeAs = data.filter(function(f) { return f.[type A] === 'A'; });
```

Comment: this is not quite the vein I was trying to hit. I have revised my question to further narrow the scope